# MySQL Over Convert from SQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datatables

Can anyone help me covert this SQL statement into MySQL.
Its being used for jQuery datatables for server side pagination.
I have tried using

```
@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
```

instead of

```
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY  item_id  asc) AS RowNumber
```

but i keep getting a  syntax error

```
             CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp1 AS (SELECT * INTO temp1 FROM item where BLOCKED='0');            

            SELECT *
            FROM
                (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY  item_id  asc) AS RowNumber , *
                    FROM
                        (SELECT (SELECT count(temp1.NO)
                                FROM
                                    temp1) AS TotalRows
                            , ( SELECT  count(NO) FROM temp1  ) AS TotalDisplayRows ,*
                        FROM
                            temp1  ) RawResults) Results
            WHERE
                RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Thanks for your help, Here is the query. But how can i return TotalRows and TotalDisplayRows into the data ?  i had to manually add the item_id and description. The colums i get outputted are RowNumber, Item_Id, Description. I also need TotalRows amd TotalDisplayRows

set @rn := 0;

```
SELECT *
              FROM (SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) AS RowNumber,item_id,description
                    FROM
                        (SELECT (SELECT count(item.item_id)
                                FROM
                                    item) AS TotalRows
                            , ( SELECT  count(item_id) FROM item  ) AS TotalDisplayRows ,item_id,description
                        FROM
                            item  ) RawResults

                        ) Results
            WHERE
                RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp1 AS (SELECT * INTO temp1 FROM item where BLOCKED='0');            
    SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) AS RowNumber , *
          FROM (SELECT (SELECT count(temp1.NO)
                        FROM temp1
                       ) AS TotalRows,
                       (SELECT count(NO) FROM temp1  ) AS TotalDisplayRows ,*
                FROM temp1 
               ) RawResults CROSS JOIN
               (SELECT @rn := 0) vars
          ORDER BY item_id
          ) Results
    WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

If you don't actually need the `RowNumber` column in the table, you could just use `limit` and `offset`.

Comment: Thanks
Have it sorted now the final query is `SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) AS RowNumber,item_id,description
          FROM (SELECT (SELECT count(item.item_id)
                        FROM item 
                       ) AS TotalRows,
                       (SELECT count(item_id) FROM item  ) AS TotalDisplayRows,item_id,description
                FROM item where BLOCKED='0'
               ) RawResults CROSS JOIN
               (SELECT @rn := 0) vars
          ) Results
    WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10`

Comment: Ive added another issue above if you have time...Thanks very much. Im looking to output the TotalRows and TotalDisplayRows into the data, not sure how to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) AS RowNumber,item_id,description
FROM
    (SELECT (SELECT count(item.item_id)
            FROM
                item) AS TotalRows
        , ( SELECT  count(item_id) FROM item  ) AS TotalDisplayRows ,item_id,description
    FROM
        item  ) RawResults
    ) Results 
    WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```